# mySQL report php problems

Tags: php, mysql, sql, report

I am havin trouble with mySQL reports.

What I have:
[My report now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6SU1D.jpg)

What I need:[My future report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ksmow.jpg)

I need to get total price of group for example screen size with 12.5', then total price of screens with their size 13.3' and so on...

I tried this:

```
public function getGroupPrice($priceFrom, $priceTo) {
    $whereClauseString = "";
    if(!empty($priceFrom)) {
        $whereClauseString .= " WHERE `{$this->pc_table}`.`price`>='{$priceFrom}'";
        if(!empty($priceTo)) {
            $whereClauseString .= " AND `{$this->pc_table}`.`price`<='{$priceTo}'";
        }
    } else {
        if(!empty($priceTo)) {
            $whereClauseString .= " WHERE `{$this->pc_table}`.`price`<='{$priceTo}'";
        }
    }


    $query = "  SELECT `{$this->screen_table}`.`size`,
                sum(`{$this->pc_table}`.`price`) AS `total_price`
                FROM `{$this->pc_table}`
                INNER JOIN `{$this->screen_table}`
                ON `{$this->pc_table}`.`fk_Screenid_Screen`=`{$this->screen_table}`.`id_Screen`
                GROUP BY `{$this->screen_table}`.`size`";

    $data = mysql::select($query);

    return $data;
}
```

And I get some nonsense data. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong, but I can see that `$whereClauseString` is intended as part of the query, but is never included in the query. Why don't you echo the query and see if it looks like what you expect?

Comment: That doesn't change anything... I think its ignorable.

Comment: The easiest way is to use PHP to total your numbers as you build your table, or iterate through each row in your getGroupPrice function to build up the total.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @Benas: Questions should not contain bugs, and they should not be ignored. I agree with aynber, you already got the data from the database, why use two different queries?

Comment: Ok, I have deleted it, but nothing changed..

Comment: I checked it in data base, seems like it works correctly, perhaps my problem is that I echo it not correctly?

Comment: @Benas: That is possible, we cannot see your output code...or much of the rest. You write: "I get some nonsense data". That is certainly not helpful. Please try to be as accurate as possible in your question. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because user data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or any user data directly in your query.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/w91WN201
this is how I try to print it. I get correct prices, but they do not categorise, they just print 5 times in beginning,